# Dot product in Eigen by multiplying by transpose?

Tags: c++, eigen

I can't seem to make it work, should it?

e.g.:

```
    Vector3d a;
    Vector3d b;
    ...
    double c = a.transpose() * b;  // Doesn't work
    double c = a.dot(b);  // Seems to work
```

I'm coming from MATLAB where a'*b is the thing. I can deal with using dot if needed, but I'd like to know if I'm just doing something dumb.

Comment: hm, which version of Eigen are you using? The following does work: `double c = a.transpose() * b;` if `a` and `b` are really column vectors at compile time like `Vector3d` or `VectorXd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In matlab, a'*b is syntactic sugar for [`dot(a, b)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html). Note that the requirement for vectors is "they must have the same length" and not that one is a row vector, and one a column. This is the same as Eigen's `a.dot(b)`.

<strike>In [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html), `a.transpose() * b` works, it just doesn't return a `double` but rather a 1x1 matrix. If you wrote it as `MatrixXd c = a.transpose() * b;` or `double c = (a.transpose() * b)[0];` it should work as expected.</strike>

That above paragraph was the case at in Eigen 2 (which apparently OP was using). Since then (Eigen 3), [@ggael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702789/dot-product-in-eigen-by-multiplying-by-transpose/33712970#comment55197877_33702789) of course, is right. This answer regarded a general case where the dimensions of `a` and `b` are not known at compile time. In the case where `Vector3d` or `VectorXd` are used, then `double c = a.transpose() * b;` works as well, not as stated in the question. With versions <= 2.0.15, the original is correct without any reservations.

Comment: So... in matlab matrix multiplication isn't associative if the matrices happen to be vectors?  That's rather tricky and dangerous.

Comment: No, Avi's note was only for the `dot()` function, not for operator `*`.

Comment: I guess I wouldn't consider a'*b syntactic sugar, since it's really a direct translation of the underlying linear algebra.  In any case, the fact that eigen returns a 1x1 matrix is sensible, and I can get the value out and make it into a scalar double.  Thanks.

Comment: In Eigen the it is rather a.dot()*b and not dot(a,b)

Comment: @Ari.stat Thanks, but that's not the right syntax either. The correct syntax is `a.dot(b)`. In any case, I corrected the syntax in the answer. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/QYoEei) for example.